# Can't pull Lightning Dashboards with Salesforce DX or FMT

Tags: reporting, dashboard, migration-tool, salesforcedx

I have a Salesforce DX project containing multiple dashboards *in the same folder*. Some of the dashboards are classic dashboards and others are lightning dashboards.

However, whenever I pull the dashboard folder with Salesforce DX or the Force.com Migration Tool only the metadata for the *classic* dashboards are retrieved.

Is there some other security setting that is not at the folder-level that could be preventing dashboards created in lightning experience from being pulled?

Could this issue be caused by something else entirely?

Edit:

The issue can be reliably reproduced as follows:

1. Create a Lightning Report/Dashboard.
2. Create a Lightning Folder.
3. Add the Report/Dashboard to the Lightning folder.
4. Run `sfdxforce:source:pull` -> only the folder metadata is retrieved.

These scenarios work reliably:

- Pull Lightning Report inside Classic folder.
- Pull Classic Report inside Lightning folder.
- Pull Classic Report inside Classic folder.

Level I and II support didn't have a fix for this issue. I was informed it cannot be escalated any further because I'm not a premier partner. It seems like this is a bug but I'm not sure if it is reproducible in other Dev Hubs.

Comment: DX is still "new", so there may be some bugs left in it. It *should* work automatically.

Comment: The DX team is very responsive to this kind of issue on their Trailblazer Community group.